# Why does the code work within <script> tag, but not in external .js file? 

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ejs

I tested out this code within a `<script>` tag, and then in an external `.js` file linked to the `.html` file. The former works; the latter doesn't. Why?

```
<script>
    const x = document.createElement('div');
    x.innerHTML = "<%=JSON.stringify(result)%>";
    console.log(JSON.parse(x.childNodes[0].nodeValue));
</script>
```

The same code placed in an external linked file gives me this error message:

```
VM125:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at my.js:3
(anonymous) @ my.js:3
```

Why?

Comment: Fairly simple, the js file isn't a template file so that ejs statement never gets compiled and the string we see in your code gets parsed but isn't json

Answer (score 1):

As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) points out, `<%=JSON.stringify(result)%>` is an ejs statement that never gets compiled.

```js
const x = document.createElement('div');
x.innerHTML = "<%=JSON.stringify(result)%>";
```

The above code creates the following HTML:

```html
<div><%=JSON.stringify(result)%></div>
```

If this were in an `.ejs` file, it would be replaced with something like:

```html
<div>"foo"</div>
```

Depending on what `JSON.stringify(result)` evaluates to (assuming `result` equals `'foo'` here).

This is a shot in the dark, but what you probably want to do is have something like this in your `.ejs` file:

```html
window.result = <%=JSON.stringify(result)%>;
```

Then replace the corresponding line of your current code with:

```js
x.innerHTML = result;
```

Basically remove the `.ejs` syntax `<%=` and `%>`.

Comment: Think you want `x.innerHTML = window.result`

Comment: For clarification, where would I put: window.result = <%=JSON.stringify(result)%>; ? would that be within <script> tag? Thanks.

Comment: @DwayneJackson Yes, within a `<script>` tag.  If you like my answer feel free to award me Best Answer by clicking the green checkmark at the top left of my answer.